# proving a matrix is symmetric to its squared version

Tags: linear-algebra

Prove: If $A^T∗A=A$, then $A$ is symmetric and $A=A^2$.

I have, $A=A^T∗A=A∗A=A^2$.

I believe it is too short. Any help?

Comment: Why does the second = hold?

Comment: because $A^T=A$

Comment: @mickey4691, but that's what you are trying to prove...

Comment: But you need to prove that $A$ is symmeteric, not assume that $A^T=A$.

Comment: I have typed up the answer and am tempted to show you, but it is beneficial if you try it on your own. It is not very difficult, I can assure you.

Comment: $A=(A^T * A)^T = A^T (A^T)^T$
that's good so far?

Comment: @mickey4691: It is unclear why the first = holds. To show that $A$ is symmetric, we need to show that $A^T=A$. So the first step is $A^T = (A^TA)^T = \cdots$

Comment: i missed the raised to the T in the first part, i'm sorry.

Comment: So you're almost there. 
$$
A^T = (A^T A)^T = A^T (A^T)^T = A^T A = ?
$$

Comment: how does $A^T (A^T)^T=A^T*A$ ?

Comment: @mickey4691: We want to show $A^T=A$. So first start with $A^T$. Then by assumption, we know that $A =A^TA$. Hence $A^T = (A^TA)^T$. Now as Omnomnomnom suggests, try to simplify the right side so that it becomes $A$.

Comment: the transpose of a transpose is itself.

Comment: i understand, thanks to both of you, especially Lee for helping me understand.

Comment: You are welcome; just treat it like a game or puzzle, and you will get it if you don't give up. For the second part (showing $A^2=A$), it is similar.

Answer (score 2):

**The solution, as given in the comments:**

We note that
$$
A^T =
(A^T A)^T = A^T (A^T)^T = A^T A = A
$$
So that $A = A^T$.  Thus, $A$ is symmetric, and $A = A^TA = (A)A = A^2$.